# Xcode 8 automatic build when editing

Tags: xcode, build, xcode8, beta

I'm using both Xcode 8 and 8.1 beta (8T61a) and when I write anything, even a single space, Xcode builds automatically the entire project, It's very annoying and make my Mac really slow I disabled "Live build" option in General setting, but nothing changes

Does someone else have this strange issue ?

Comment: I have same problem. Do you find out any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable "Automatically Refresh Views" from the Editor section.It is happening because, as soon as you type anything, XCode refreshes the views as they might change due to any changes in code.

Follow this link [Xcode 8 automatic build when any change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45160746/xcode-8-automatic-build-when-any-change/45160866#45160866)[image]