# Xcode 8 automatic build when any change

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using both Xcode 8.2.1 and when I write anything, even a single space, Xcode builds automatically the entire project, It's very annoying and make my Mac really slow I disabled "Live build" option in General setting, C language to compiler default in build phase  but nothing changes. Any one know about it?

Comment: Is there any storyboard or xib open in the Assistant Editor?

Comment: yes i open in Assistant Editor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to disable "Automatically Refresh Views" from the Editor section.

[image]

It is happening because, as soon as you type anything, XCode refreshes the views as they might change due to any changes in code.

Follow this link [Xcode keeps building storyboard after each keystroke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476030/xcode-keeps-building-storyboard-after-each-keystroke)

Comment: thank you so much this solution is working

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to disable **Show Live Issues** in Preference -> General already?

[image]

Comment: yes but same issue